# If $A$ is an orthogonal matrix with $|A|=-1$, show that $|I-A|=0$

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, determinant, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix where $A$ is of even order with $|A|=-1.$ Show that, $|I-A|=0,$ where $I$ denotes the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

---

**My approach**

$A \cdot A^{\top}=I$

$|A| \cdot\left|A^{\top}\right|=1 \quad$ or $\quad\left|A^{\top}\right|=-1.....(2)$

let $A=\left[\begin{array}{ll}a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right]$

$L = I-A$

$L=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1-a & -b \\ -c & 1-d\end{array}\right]; \quad 2 a d=2 b c$(from eq2)

$|L|=(1-a)(1-d) - bc$

$=-(a+d)$

*What to do next?*
**Am I going wrong?**

Comment: How does $ad=bc$ follow from eq2?

Comment: Also imo this might be difficult to generalize to higher dimension.

Comment: $A$ is a reflection, so it need not have $+1$ as an eigenvalue. For example take $n=1$, $A=-1$, so $A-1\ne0$.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $|A+I|=0$?

Comment: What is an even orthogonal matrix?

Comment: $A$ is similar to a block-diagonal matrix where the blocks are either scalar or $2 \times 2$ rotation matrices. Then show that the “actually diagonal” part cannot consist of only $-1$s.

Comment: @Divide1918 solve the eq ,u will get it

Comment: @Divide1918 I assumed *even* stood for *matrix with an even order*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $A$ is orthogonal, rewrite $\det(I-A)$ as follows:
$$\begin{align}\det(I-A)&=\det(A^TA-A)\\&=\det(A)\det(A^T-I)\\&=\det(A)\det((A^T-I)^T)\\&=-\det(A-I)\end{align}$$ It follows that $$\det(I-A)=(-1)^{n+1}\det(I-A)$$ As $n$ is even, we get $$\boxed{\det(I-A)=0}$$

as desired.

Comment: @ VIVID how do u able to take whole transpose?

Comment: @AmartyaRoy $\det(M)=\det(M^T)$

Comment: one more doubt , how det((A^T−I)^T)=det(A−I)?

Comment: @AmartyaRoy, Using the facts $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$ and $(A^T)^T=A$, one obtains $$(A^T-I)^T=(A^T)^T-I^T=A-I$$

Comment: thanks a lot for your response!  
I don't understand why I didn't notice this fundamental property.so silly of me :(